# BigQuery - Grouping by date with a WHERE clause

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

My goal is to search for certain products, count the total per certain product, and group **each** by day.

Schema is like so:

| line_items.sku | created_at |
| --- | --- |
| product1 | 2020-04-02T13:22:44 |
| product2 | 2020-04-02T05:01:22 |
| product2 | 2020-04-03T14:21:10 |

My query is below:

```sql
SELECT
  EXTRACT(DAY
  FROM
    CAST(`order`.created_at AS DATETIME)) AS day_extracted,
  EXTRACT(MONTH
  FROM
    CAST(`order`.created_at AS DATETIME)) AS month_extracted,
  `order`.line_items.sku AS sku
FROM
  `mydatabase`
WHERE
  `order`.line_items.sku = "product 1"
  OR `order`.line_items.sku = "product 2"
```

The data is below:

| row | day_extracted | month_extracted | sku |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | 2 | product1 |
| 2 | 4 | 1 | product2 |
| 2 | 4 | 1 | product1 |

This is great and works, but I'm running into issues with needing to grouping the products and count **per product** total per day.

What am I doing wrong? If I add

```sql
  GROUP BY month_extracted, day_extracted
```

to the query, another error comes up

```
SELECT list expression references `order`.line_items which is neither grouped nor aggregated at [8:3]
```

Line 8 is:

`` `order`.line_items.sku AS sku ``

Comment: Just adding the `GROUP BY` mentioned to the query above should not cause any errors.  You should include the full query which is generating this error message.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen updated question, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order in which a general SQL query is evaluated is this[image]

Which means the group by clause doesn't even know what is `month_extracted, day_extracted`. So in order to fix this, either put the whole exp `EXTRACT(..` in Group by OR. Use a subquery. And also there is a rule, that anything in SELECT which is not part of  GROUP BY should be applied an AGGREGATE function. In your it is not hence an error.

```sql
select 
       day_extracted,
       month_extracted,
       any_value(sku) AS sku -- i used any_value to fix it, you can use any other agg. function as per your logic
 from (
SELECT
  EXTRACT(DAY
  FROM
    CAST(`order`.created_at AS DATETIME)) AS day_extracted,
  EXTRACT(MONTH
  FROM
    CAST(`order`.created_at AS DATETIME)) AS month_extracted,
    `order`.line_items.sku as Sku
  
FROM
  `mydatabase`
WHERE
  `order`.line_items.sku = "product 1"
  OR `order`.line_items.sku = "product 2"
) as _table
group by day_extracted,month_extracted
```

Answer (score 1):

[Mr.Batra](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6062292/mr-batra) led me down the rabbit hole of subqueries and that led me to my solution. Knowing which order queries are executed in made more sense now too.

```sql
SELECT day_extracted,month_extracted,Sku,count(*) FROM 
    (
SELECT
    EXTRACT(DAY
    FROM
      CAST(`order`.created_at AS DATETIME)) AS day_extracted,
    EXTRACT(MONTH
    FROM
      CAST(`order`.created_at AS DATETIME)) AS month_extracted,
    `order`.line_items.sku AS Sku
  FROM
    `mydatabase`
  WHERE
    `order`.line_items.sku = "product1"
    OR `order`.line_items.sku = "product2"
    ) AS temp
    GROUP BY temp.Sku,day_extracted,month_extracted
    ORDER BY day_extracted
```

This gives me the data in this format:

| day_extracted | month_extracted | Sku | col1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | product1 | 41 |
| 1 | 2 | product2 | 55 |
| 2 | 2 | product1 | 91 |

Comment: if my answer help please upvote and accept it. This helps us motivate answering your next question.